# How do you google for questions about an actual "stack overflow" on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, search

Just as the title says. I am getting everything, except what I need.  Searching for the phrase, "stack-overflow", doesn't limit itself to questions about the call stack.

If searching for the exact message worked in my case, then I wouldn't be asking this question.  Either you hit the exact phrase or as you add search terms, the less likely you are to find a question about an actual stack overflow.  There's a tag of "stack-overflow", but when you ask google for the exact "stack-overflow" the results aren't limited to the tag, because for google ( it seems ), "stack-overflow" is the same as "stack overflow" which is on every single page, and therefore has almost zero weight in the search results.  If the tag was "stack-overflow-tag", then searching for the tag would be helpful ---> "stackoverflowexception"..... and I'm not having that luxury in .net.

Comment: really depends on the context, but if it's a specific language, you typically get a lot further by googling the exact error message. Notably, `stackoverflow` might get you the site, but `stackoverflowexception` (Java + possibly others) get you specific questions. Qualifying with a language or just more trace details also helps

Comment: [This "Java stackoverflow" search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+stackoverflow+site%3Astackoverflow.com&sxsrf=APq-WBu5gIpk63peLhm8nQbWNDiY1Z4yFA%3A1646583201806&ei=od0kYujPMMjQaLKNr-gB&ved=0ahUKEwiopNi28LH2AhVIKBoKHbLGCx0Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=java+stackoverflow+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BAgjECc6BggAEBYQHjoICAAQFhAKEB46BggAEA0QHjoICAAQCBANEB46BwghEAoQoAFKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFiHJ2CZKGgAcAF4AIABlwKIAcgakgEGMC4yMy4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) seems to give reasonable results (even in SO Spanish if it helps...)

Comment: Interestingly you posted this question on Main, with the [tag:stack-overflow] tag which is NOT for questions about the site, but rather about the error you're asking about... So the site's search might even work for you...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - It really doesn't work at all unless someone is trying to demonstrate it works.  The more terms searched, the less weight "stackoverflow" gets in the results.   Search for Java stackoverflow gives you questions about stackoverflow errors.  Search for java stackoverflow java virtual machine - all terms included in one of the questions returned in the first search ... and zero questions about stackoverflows are returned.  https://www.google.com/search?q=java+stackoverflow+site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+virtual+machine

Comment: I dunno. I think questions about stack overflows on Stack Overflow will lead to dangerous levels of recursion.

Answer (score -3):

If one wants to search StackOverflow.com for issues only related to the stack-overflow tag, one must use the search on the site and its tag syntax, not google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow+json.net returns 3 questions.  The similar looking search via google, https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stack-overflow%22+%22json.net%22, returns 73,300 results.